# How can I use **require** in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I ClojureScript I can do something within a **ns** declaration like like:

```
(ns demo2
  (:require
    [goog.ui.Textarea               :as text-area]
  )
)
```

: but :

```
(require '[goog.ui.Textarea :as text-area])
```

: doesn't work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no (require) definition in ClojureScript.

As stated in the [wiki page](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure) on namespaces:

> You must use the :as form of :require

Comment: Thanks. It was an oversight on my part :)